# JWT in http only cookie is getting undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am setting access_token in login route but I am getting `undefined`.
Lines commented below in the code gives undefined why so? How to access the cookie when it is set ? There is another GET route /transactions which gets called on home page after login is success in that route as well I am getting undefined why so? I have also used cookie-parser in server.js file but still not working

transaction GET route https://pastebin.com/DP0NZL5W

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const User = require('../models/userSchema');

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    const {email, password} = req.body;

    console.log("Server Login email: ", email);
    console.log("Server Login password: ", password);

    User.find({email: email})
        .exec()
        .then(user => {

            console.log("User login user: ", user);

            if(user.length < 1){
                console.log("user length less")
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth failed'
                });
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
                if(err){
                    return res.status(401).json({
                        message: 'Auth failed'
                    });
                }
                if(result){
                    const token = jwt.sign({
                        email: user[0].email,
                        userId: user[0]._id
                    }, 'secret', {
                        expiresIn: "1h"
                    })

                    console.log("Cookie token: ", token);

                    res.cookie('access_token', token, { maxAge: 9000000, httpOnly: true });

                    // console.log("req.cookies: ", req.cookies)

                    // console.log("req.cookies['access_token']: ", req.cookies['access_token'])

                    return res.status(200).json({
                        message: 'Auth successful',
                        token: token
                    })
                }
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Auth failed'
                });
            })

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })

});
```

Comment: Are you expecting causality to be reversed? A request is a *cause* and a response is the *effect*, obviously the request can't contain a cookie that gets set by the response.

Comment: @Lennholm So you are saying req.cookies.access_token will be undefined in login route?

Comment: Unless the browser (or whatever makes the request) already has it and includes it in the request when it sends it to your server, yes.

Comment: @Lennholm Same code when I use React Native it shows the req.cookies.access_token gets logged in backend console but when using react it shows undefined why is this happening?

Comment: req.cookies shows the cookies in the request, It has no relation with the cookie you have set in the line above it. req.cookies will return a cookie if only a cookie exists in the browser of the agent who is requesting this Api, and also he must allow sending the cookies with the request.

Comment: @nasserahmed009  so now when login is sucess I decode the token in GET transactions route but token is undefined why is this happening?

Comment: @Lennholm so now when login is sucess I decode the token in GET transactions route but token is undefined why is this happening?

Comment: @rockstone I would assume that the React Native client you're using already has an `access_token` cookie set that it's including in the request, it's not because you set it on the response. Why do you expect this cookie to exist on the request in the login end-point anyway? The purpose of a login end-point is to create a session when there is no valid session. In other words, if the `access_token` cookie exists and is valid there would be no need to log in since you're already logged in. The login end-point should set the cookie so that the client includes it in **subsequent** requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use({
 credentials: true, // enable cookie receiving
 origin: "url of client side" // how can use your api
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.